# How can i use a switch case that has a case that does all the cases before

Tags: java, switch-statement

So i am doing a simple menu in main class where it has 10 options from 0 to 9, i am using a switch case to get the option and then execute a certain code, and number 9 is to do all the options in the menu.
How can that if option is 9, it does me all the cases before.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    switch (option) {
        case 1:
            do A;
            break;
        case 2:
            do B;
            break;
        case 3:
            do C;
            break;
        case 4:
            do C;
            break;
        case 5:
            do C;
            break;
        case 6:
            do C;
            break;
        case 9:
            do case 1 ;
            do case 2 ;
            do case 3 ;
            do case 4 ;
            do case 5 ;
            do case 6 ;
    }
}
```

I am expecting that when option is 9, it executes all the cases before;

Comment: simply `case9: do A; do B ..`

Comment: `if (option == 1 || option == 9) { doA(); } if (option == 2 || option == 9) { doB(); } if ((option >= 3 && option <= 6) || option == 9) { doC(); } `

Comment: If the problem is that `do A;` is a fair amount of code and you don't want to repeat it all in `case 9`, move the logic to a method and call the method from both `case 1` and `case 9`. That is one of the main purposes of methods: Reusable logic.

Comment: Yes i could do that but in my code i am using system.out.println() and i can only use them in main, if i put everything in separated methods it would be alot of code repeated too. I cant use system.out.println because im gonna implement it later on javaFx

Comment: It just got in my mind that if option is 9, then i can create a for loop that goes trought 1 to 8 and does all the cases

Comment: @AntonioPinto Hey! If you've figured out an answer on your own (or through the help of someone else's answer), be sure to accept an answer or write your own answer and accept that.

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways to achieve what you need. I'll outline a few.

**Use methods**

This is simple, and somewhat clean and easy to maintain. All you need to do is wrap the code you would like to execute in each case in a separate method then call those methods from within the switch. This is exactly what functions are for.

```java
switch(option){
    case 1:
        doA();
        break;
    case 2:
        doB();
        break;
    ...
    // other cases
    ...
    case 9:
        doA();
        doB();
        ...
        // other method calls
        ...
        break;
}
```

**Switch to `if` statements**

This is pretty self explanatory, just check if the option is each different case or option 9.

```java
if(option == 1 || option == 9){
    do A;
}
if(option == 2 || option == 9){
    do B;
}
...
// other cases
...
```

**(Mis)use `break`s**

This is fairly ugly and I wouldn't recommend it but it's really up to personal preference (and how easy to read and maintain you want the code to be in the future).

If `option` is `9`, then we flip a flag to turn off all breaks in the switch statement. This effectively makes all other cases below it just execute linearly (as the breaks to leave the switch are disabled).

```java
boolean isCase9 = false;
switch(option){
    case 9:
        isCase9 = true;
    case 1:
        doA();
        if(!isCase9){
            break;
        }
    case 2:
        doB();
        if(!isCase9){
            break;
        }
    ...
    // other cases
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest defining a method (let's call it `switchMethod`) with the `switch case` - when all options are only 0 to 8.

```
public void switchMethod(option) {
   switch (option) {
   case 1:
       do A;
       break;
   case 2:
      do B;
      break;
   case 3:
      do C;
      break;
   ....
   case 8:
      do X;
      break;
  }
}
```

In the `main`:

```
if (option < 9) {
    switchMethod(option)
} else {
   for (int i = 0; i <9; i++)
       switchMethod(i)
}
```

That way you won't write duplicate code and it will do the logic you requested.

Another way is doing duplicate code like that:

```
switch (option) {
    case 1:
        do A;
        break;
    case 2:
        do B;
        break;
    case 3:
        do C;
        break;
    case 4:
        do C;
        break;
    case 5:
        do C;
        break;
    case 6:
        do C;
        break;
    case 9:
        do A;
        do B;
        do C;
        ....
        break;
}
```